# Off-by-one site icons?

Tags: bug, favicon

For the past few days I've noticed that *some* icons in

1. the Hot Network Questions on the right side of my browser window, and
2. the "A list of all Stack Exchange sites" dropdown in the menu bar

have been incorrect, and that they are incorrect by exactly one index in the alphabetical list of the URLs (not the names) of the SE sites.  Here's one example of problem #1 from a few minutes ago on **money.**:

[image: Hot Network Questions from Money.SE]

- The top link is to a question on **workplace.**, but the icon is for **worldbuilding.**.
- The second icon is fine.
- The third link is to a question on **unix.**, but the icon is for **ux.**.
- The fourth icon is fine.
- The last link is to a question on **money.**, but the icon is for **movies.**.

As for problem #2, right now on stackoverflow.com here's what part of my dropdown looks like:

[image: All sites dropdown from stackoverflow.com]

I don't know what all of these icons are, but I don't think any of them are correct.  The icon for **tex.** is from **tor.**, **workplace.**'s is from **worldbuilding.** again, **tor.**'s is from **travel.**, **travel.**'s is from **tridion.**, **tridion.**'s is from **ukrainian.**, etc.

Note that this does not always happen.  Sometimes all the icons are fine both in Hot Network Questions and in the dropdown.  Sometimes only some are wrong.

Also note that I'm behind a firewall that occasionally causes problems when loading things over HTTPS.  But I've not seen this particular problem behind this firewall before.

Comment: Ack.  I started posting this on meta.money.SE because I thought the problem was limited to that site.  It wasn't a duplicate there.  Then I noticed that it affected other sites, so I moved it here without checking for duplicates.  Note: I'm not sure if the other questions noted that the problem affected the dropdown as well.

Comment: it's all the same problem, unfortunately; these icons are mashed into one big sprite file and referenced by position - adding a new site screws that up until everyone gets a new sprite file.

Comment: @Shog I assume that means you’re changing the positions of existing icons when you update the sprite? Can’t you just, ya know, not do that?

Comment: A wise man once said, "Do not meddle in the affairs of designers, for you are crunchy and good with ketchup." But a plausible explanation here is that these are compiled via a process that's unable to identify which icon(s) are new. @Cai

Comment: @Shog indeed, good advice. But (and I say so as a designer) any process that causes this many bug reports every time it is run probably need re-thinking :)

Comment: I tend to agree; this is annoying.

Comment: @Shog9: Sounds like that sprite sheet URL should have a version tag, just like the JS and CSS files have. Except that, looking at the icons in the inspector, it looks like it already does! For some reason it's just not doing what it's supposed to do. :/